# LogLevel rewrite does not log

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, joomla, url-rewriting, virtual-hosts

I'm attempting to debug rewriting in a joomla website on xampp. What I observe is the following

1. the website is working
2. After I enable **URL rewrite** in the Joomla BE none of the links work, but the main page still works. I conclude that the rewrite is not working proper.
3. I have activated (renamed) the .htaccess in the root
4. I've added **LogLevel warn rewrite:trace6** to the httpd.conf and restarted Apache.

I've consulted http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging
and http://docs.joomla.org/Enabling_Search_Engine_Friendly_(SEF)_URLs

Not sure if this is relevant, but my websites are configured with:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 UseCanonicalName Off
 VirtualDocumentRoot "D:/srv/htdocs/%2/%1"
 ServerAlias *.*.localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

in httpd-vhosts.conf that enables me to have multiple websites

But even if I configure it as a non virtual host it still does not create log entries for rewrite, neither in error_log nor in access_log.

Answer (score 3):

I'm also running a vhost on WAMP using Apache 2.4.17 and here is my config in the httpd-vhosts.conf file in order to get a proper log file :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine On
    LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6
    ErrorLog "C:\Users\.....\Desktop\log.txt"
    ServerName .....
    DocumentRoot ....
    <Directory  ....>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try **alert** instead of **warn** for debugging. I.e.: `LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6` 
In addition, your log file was possibly not flushed when you looked into it. Check also that you are looking in the right log file. Search for 'ErrorLog' in the Apache configuration file.